# Enable SSL in MySQL and PostgreSQL server

Tags: mysql, ssl-certificate, postgresql-9.5

Currently, I have used the **MySQL 6.5** and **PostgreSQL 9.5 version**. I need to enable(Configure) SSL in both servers. I have now (.pfx) SSL certificate. Can you please suggest me to how to configure the SSL in both servers. I have searched a lot of documents on online but I didn't get any clear idea about that.

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

For PostgreSQL you will need a crt and key file.
To get the crt, Key file you can use following commands -

```
openssl pkcs12 -in [yourfile.pfx] -nocerts -out [keyfile-encrypted.key]
openssl pkcs12 -in [yourfile.pfx] -clcerts -nokeys -out [certificate.crt]
```

Note you may have to use pkcs8/pkcs7 depending on your pfx file.

this is now to be used in your postgresql.conf file, refer the article to identify the attributes that you need to set in here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/runtime-config-connection.html

keys are - ssl_cert_file ,ssl_key_file